# How to work Dispatch_Sempahore when first call signal and

Tags: swift, dispatchsemaphore

During the DispatchSemaphore function,
Is it OK to call Signal() first and Wait() later?
If call Signal() N continuously, does the value internally become N,
Or I wonder if invoking Signal() several times does not increase the value when Wait() is not called.

```
let sempahore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
semaphore.signal()
semaphore.signal()
semaphore.signal()
// in time, what is sempahore value? 1 or 3?

sempahore.wait()
// in time, what is semaphore value? 0 or 2?
// wait for more signal? or not?
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happens if you call `sempahore.wait()` twice, thrice, or four times in a row? Which one blocks?

Comment: yes I did it.
Despite having multiple Wait() numbers,
A single call to Signal() will unlock the lock.
I don't know what's wrong with you.
Is it related to init Value when initializing Semaphore?

Comment: @Viktor: This question is not specific to Swift 5. Please add the [swift5] tag (or other version related tags) only for questions about the language changes in that particular version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `.signal` is '+1', and every `.wait` is '-1' or `block` as documented, and code that demo is

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
semaphore.signal() // = 1
semaphore.signal() // = 2
semaphore.signal() // = 3

semaphore.wait() // = 2  - pass
semaphore.wait() // = 1  - pass
semaphore.wait() // = 0  - pass
semaphore.wait() // = -1 - hang - waiting for new signal()
```

Here is from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore)

> You increment a semaphore count by calling the signal() method, and
>   decrement a semaphore count by calling wait() or one of its variants
>   that specifies a timeout.
>
> ```
> @discardableResult func signal() -> Int
> Discussion
> Increment the counting semaphore. If the previous value was less than zero, 
>   this function wakes a thread currently waiting
>
> func wait()
> Discussion
> Decrement the counting semaphore. If the resulting value is less than zero, 
>   this function waits for a signal to occur before returning.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If gave the initial value of semaphore to N instead of zero,
Does this increase with N+1,N+2,N+3 every time I call Signal()?

Comment: Yes, it does. If in answered example you set the initial value as 1 (instead of 0), then forth call of `wait` do pass.